Why does the camera jump when the raycast hits an object?
I have a problem in Unity v2023, using the basic raycast from the player's camera view, and when I hit something I want (a particular layer), the camera moves itself for no reason.
I found on YT a guy who had this problem too, here is the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faY50bf4oWs
just put 0:43s, to see the problem.
My code is very simple:
public static PlayerViewTrigger Instance { get; private set; }

[SerializeField] private Transform viewTriggerPos;
private bool eleanorCamp;

private void Awake()
{
    if (Instance != null && Instance != this) { Destroy(this); }
    else { Instance = this; }
}

private void Update()
{
    ViewTrigger();
}

private void ViewTrigger()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(viewTriggerPos.position, viewTriggerPos.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out RaycastHit hit, 50f))
    {
        if (hit.collider.CompareTag("EleanorCamp") && !eleanorCamp)
        {
            eleanorCamp = true;
            SceneManager_02_Camp.Instance.EleanorSpot();
        }
    }
}

and SceneManager script:
public void EleanorSpot()
{
    BackgroundAudio.Instance.audioDarkForest.Play();
    horrorAudioSource1.PlayOneShot(horrorAudioClip1);
    Invoke("HideEleanor", 3f);

    jessyWaterDialogTrigger.SetActive(false);
    jessyWaterDialogStartTrigger.SetActive(false);
}

private void HideEleanor()
{
    horrorAudioSource2.PlayOneShot(horrorAudioClip2);
    fireParticles.SetActive(false);

    eleanor.SetActive(false);
    eleanorTrigger = false;

    Invoke("JessyScream1", 5f);
}

private void JessyScream1()
{
    ShowJessy(5);
    jessy_bathroom1_AudioSource.PlayOneShot(jessy_scream1_AudioClip);
    JessyGoesToBathroom_LimitMovementTrigger.SetActive(false);
    Invoke("HenryShout1", .8f);
}

private void HenryShout1()
{
    PlayerSounds.Instance.voiceAudioSource.PlayOneShot(PlayerSounds.Instance.jessyBathroom_2);
    JessyGoesToBathroom_Scream2.SetActive(true);
}

This is code for Camera rotation (look)
private void PlayerCameraRotate()
{
    rotationXAxis += Input.GetAxis(mouseYInput) * cameraSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    rotationYAxis += Input.GetAxis(mouseXInput) * cameraSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    rotationXAxis = Mathf.Clamp(rotationXAxis, -upDownLookRange, upDownLookRange + 20f);

    hand.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-rotationXAxis, rotationYAxis, 0f);

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.localRotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, rotationYAxis, 0f), cameraAcceleration * Time.deltaTime);
    playerCamera.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(playerCamera.localRotation, Quaternion.Euler(-rotationXAxis, 0f, 0f), cameraAcceleration * Time.deltaTime);
}


This question only includes [tag:c#], and no [tag:unityscript]. Updating tags accordingly.

theres a lot in scenemanager not relevant here, however, there is also a lot missing.. such as what the many "triggers" in the scenemanager are, and what they do, i also think that you maybe assuming the invoke waits before doing the next line

I doubt the "jump" happens in the code you provided ... just because another user has similar issues (and btw providing way more code context including in particular code that moves and rotates objects) doesn't mean that the cause is the same for your case

The camera jump is either the result of a script modifying the camera's game object position (or it's parents in the hierarchy) or the result of auto physics simulation (contact resolving).
To aid debugging, make sure your camera is a root game object in the scene instead of being a child somewhere, then make sure it does not include any physical component such as rigidbody.
